# How to install X-Ray texture pack for 1.6.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Im trying to download a minecraft x-ray texture pack. I've tried this one: http://www.curse.com/texture-packs/minecraft/x-ray-craft/ but it doesn't work, because it's for 1.5.2.

Please help me find and install a texture pack to help with mining.

Comment: I've edited your question to be more reader-friendly. I've changed the version to 1.6.2 - you play the latest Minecraft, right?

Answer (score 3):

Texture Packs no longer work for Minecraft 1.6+, since they've been replaced by [Resource Packs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_pack). You have to convert old texture packs into resource packs to use them now.

To convert a 1.5-compatible texture pack, use Mojang's [Texture Ender](http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/utilities/TextureEnder.jar) tool to repack it into a resource pack format.

To convert a 1.4 or earlier texture pack, first "unstitch" the texture pack into a 1.5-compatible texture pack using Mojang's [Unstitcher](http://assets.minecraft.net/unstitcher/unstitcher.jar) tool. Then use the Texture Ender above to convert that 1.5-compatible texture pack into a resource pack.

---

**Note that using an x-ray texture pack on a server can get you banned.** It claims to "not be detectable", and that's true in the most trivial sense because the client doesn't report what texture pack it's using. Server operators have long since tackled that challenge though and come up with ways to detect when a player is behaving in a way only possible with an "undetectable" x-ray cheat. Servers often have plugins that track players who are getting more than their share of diamonds or kills, and notify the admin that the player may need banning. Some sophisticated statistical plugins are also available that auto-ban players that behave in ways that are only possible with an x-ray pack.